# Is it possible to display active directory information popup like in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, active-directory

In SharePoint when you hover over a user's name a popup appears with their details from AD, like in Outlook, like this...

[image: AD Popup]

How is this done and is it possible to do the same in my own ASP.NET websites using whatever SharePoint has to do this? We have a staff Intranet I would like to do this in.

Comment: not sure if you can get the same control but it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the [javascript directly from the SharePoint page](http://geekswithblogs.net/jacobladams/archive/2011/05/03/use-hmtl-and-javascript-to-display-presence-controls-in-sharepoint.aspx), e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepointsite/_layouts/1033/init.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepointsite/_layouts/1033/core.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
img.presenceIndicator
{
   border-style:None;
   height:12px;
   width:12px;
   border-width:0px;
   vertical-align: middle
}
</style>
<span>
   <img id="uniqueID" onload="IMNRC('jadams@example.com', 
   getElementById('uniqueID'))" ShowOfflinePawn="1" 
   src=http://sharepointsite/_layouts/images/blank.gif 
   class="presenceIndicator"/>

   <a href="someCustomUserProfilePage.aspx?UserID=adamsjl">Adams, Jacob L.</a>
</span>
```

, or use [these codeplex controls](http://htmlpresencecontrols.codeplex.com/).